# How to create a PFFile from a url in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Given a URL to a PFFile inside parse, how can I go about reconstituting the PFFile?

I can't find anything in the docs that explains this process. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code of PFFile does not allow reconstituting a PFFile from url, the only way is keeping in memory the instance of PFFile used to save the data. This is frustrating as we can't persist it to local in order to use it later.

I'm researching for an alternative to this too. If anyone can help us, it would be welcome.

Answer (score 4):

`PFFile` has a private constructor that you can use to create an instance from an url and a file name.

Just add the following code to your bridging header :

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface PFFile (PrivateAdditions)
+ (instancetype)fileWithName:(NSString *)name url:(NSString *)url;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

You can use it in Swift like so :

```
let file = PFFile.file(withName: fileName, url: fileURL)
```

The file name should match the last path component of the url.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @deadbeef. Is the name *required* to be the the same as the last path component of the url? And, if so, do you happen to have a snippet to extract that? Been trying to move to Swift from Obj-C and I've been slowed down by the learning curve. Also, do you know if this creates a new PFFile on the server? Am I able to use this PFFile with a PFImageView?

Comment: The easiest way is to create an `URL` object from the url string and use its `lastPathComponent` property like so : `URL(string: "http://.../fileName.ext")?.lastPathComponent`. This doesn't create the file on the server, the file has to already exist. You can use it wherever you would use a regular `PFFile` (including `PFImageView`)

Comment: The name is not *required* to match the last path component, but since you are reconstructing an existing `PFFile`, it *should* match because when Parse creates files, it always does.

Comment: Awesome. So it looks like the name is easy to grab, but also unnecessary if I'm *only* displaying this image, not doing any sort of saving or attaching it to an object?

Comment: This is private API, which means there is probably no safeguard against erroneous usage. If I were you I would use it exactly as it was intended to be used.